# -D arguments not recognized in hadoop jar command (using spring)

Tags: spring, hadoop

Below is the command that I am running

```
hadoop jar <path>/<some jar> -Dext.properties.dir=path of properties file>
```

My spring config has the below entry...

```
context:property-placeholder  location="classpath:main/resources/properties/app.properties,file:${ext.properties.dir}/app-qa.properties"
```

But when i run it, I see the below error

```
 Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException:      ${ext.properties.dir}/app-qa.properties (No such file or directory)
```

The below works though

```
java jar <path>/<some jar> -Dext.properties.dir=path of properties file
```

Can someone help me debug this?

Comment: May be the issue is happening because i am not giving quotes around ${ext.properties.dir}. But how can i give quotes since there is already a quote for the entire location field. I even tried escaping the quotes, but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Don't confuse setting Hadoop properties using -D property=value  option to GenericOptionsParser with setting JVM system properties using -Dproperty=value.

JVM doesn't allow any whitespace whereas GenericOptionsParser requires.

Comment: Chirag - I tried both the options, but neither of them are working. Ideally, in this case -Dproperty=value need to be set